# List of function in one thread python

Tags: python, multithreading

Any way to send a list of python functions to a thread?

I currently have something like this:

```
   t = threading.Thread (target = lambda q, arg1: q.put (authTestFunction (args.username, args.password, args.ip, args.secret, args.timeout)), args = (queu,))
```

but I need to send a list of functions to be done in a single thread and so on something like this:

```
   t = threading.Thread (target = lambda q, arg1: q.put (authTestFunction (args.username, args.password, args.ip, args.secret, args.timeout), authTestFunction (args.username, args.password, args.ip, args.secret, args.timeout), authTestFunction (args.username, args.password, args.ip, args.secret, args.timeout)), args = (queu,))
```

Comment: Do you expect the thread to execute the functions one after the other? If so, why not simply send a function / lambda that actually calls them one after another?

Comment: I need to execute in a thread 100 functions for example
 

to be able for example 5 threads with 100 functions and so on and I need them to be parallel

Comment: Have you looked at all at `multiprocessing` and the Pool class? It's still not clear whether you expect your 100 function to somehow get parallelised - threads aren't magic and they're not even actually parallel, you'll need processes for that. Also, the example you're giving seems to suggest that the function you're looking to process is rather trivial (an authentication operation)?